# How do I transform metrics.exe XML file with XSD?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am working with the Code Metrics tool from Microsoft.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/camerons/archive/2011/01/28/code-metrics-from-the-command-line.aspx

I have the output file as an XML file.  How do I load it into the metrics.XSD so I can view the relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got things mixed up. [An XSD file defines the format of an XML file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema) whereas it is [XSL files that are used for transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Transformations).

There is an [XSLT file that purports to be what you want](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/camerons/archive/2011/02/20/code-metrics-reporting-and-xslt-debugging.aspx). I will be investigating it today or tomorrow.
( For people who haven't seen it, the command-line metrics tool is: [Visual Studio Code Metrics PowerTool 10.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9422) )